# Insert SQL in Java syntax

Tags: java, sql, insert

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pizzabaseaccount", "root", "");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    String sql ="insert into pizzaorder (PizzaType,PizzaChosen,ToppingsDetails,CrustType,PizzaSize,PizzaQuantities,PizzaTotalPrice)"
        +"values ('"+pizzatype+"','"+pizzachosen+"','"+toppingsdetails+"','"+crusttype+"','"+pizzasize+"','"+pizzaquantities+"','"+totalprice+"')";

    st.executeQuery(sql);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Order Complete");
}catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
}
```

I get "Error". It wont insert the data on the pizzabaseaccount database. pizzaorder is the table name btw. I don't know whats wrong with the code. Im a beginner on Java. Btw, the pizzatype , pizzachosen, toppingdetails, crusttype, pizzasize, pizzaquantities, and totalprice are String variables.

Comment: PLEASE use bind parameters!

Comment: What Error is being thrown? What happened when you debugged? What's the content of the String `sql` after its creation? What happened when you tried other queries?

Comment: Never catch and swallow exceptions! always print the stacktrace from catch block to identify the exception.

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error"); <-- this Error message

Comment: what is bind parameters?

Comment: What happens when a customer orders a large `','','','','','','');drop database; --`?

Comment: uh no. the String variables has already the data of the order details. I just wanted to insert the data in String variables to the database.

Comment: (1.) Do `ex.printStackTrace()` to see where the problem is.

(2.) For `insert` query, do `st.executeUpdate(sql)`.

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; this is the error message

Comment: @rubyrose print the sql String in console and copy the query and run it in your database gui and update the question with the output error

Answer (score 0):

Check that pizzatype pizzachosen and all the others do not contains the "'" carachter; if so, you should escape it.
Anyway, this is not a good way to create an SQL query.
Use bind parameters --> read the API reference

Comment: i dont know how to do that bind parameters.